# Cakephp span in Html link

Tags: cakephp

I have this code

```
<li id="Tiempo">
   <?= $this->Html->link(__('En Tiempo'), ['action' => 'index', 'Tiempo']) ?><span class="label label-success ml-10"><?php echo $entiempo ?></span>
</li>
```

But i want the span into a but I don't know how

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to modify the content/title of the link. As the docs point out, this is the first parameter of [HtmlHelper->link()](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/html.html#Cake%5CView%5CHelper%5CHtmlHelper::link). To add the span inside your a tag you have 2 options.

### Add the Span in the Link

You could either modify it directly and set the escape options to false:

```
<li id="Tiempo">
    <?= $this->Html->link('<span class="label label-success ml-10">' . $entiempo . '</span>', ['action' => 'index', 'Tiempo'], ['escape' => false]) ?>
</li>
```

### Modify the template

Or you modify the template HtmlHelper uses.

```
$this->Html->setTemplates([
    'link' => '<a href="{{url}}"{{attrs}}><span class="label label-success ml-10">{{content}}</span></a>',
]);
```

and use the link() method like this:

```
<?= $this->Html->link($entiempo, ['action' => 'index', 'Tiempo']) ?>
```

See [Changing the Tags Output by HtmlHelper](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/html.html#changing-the-tags-output-by-htmlhelper)